# Node/React app won't deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I've tried everything I can think of and exhausted google searches. I've already ruled out the most common problems (ex: not using process.env.PORT in app.listen).

Here are the heroku logs:

```
2018-07-18T02:43:26.705491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-river-42936.herokuapp.com request_id=78261d20-9656-4f24-9a50-6a8e90fe216f fwd="104.32.39.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-18T02:43:28.104845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-river-42936.herokuapp.com request_id=dab234a8-b9d7-4bbe-aa2b-36e6c4b2fcc9 fwd="104.32.39.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
```

And here is the [server.js file](https://github.com/gigamesh/auth/blob/master/server/server.js)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see you've not defined a `'/'` path, are you able to navigate to `/api/user`?

Comment: Shouldn't be any error, try restart the application and access the path you've defined.

Comment: @RodrigoMata I've tried entering multiple paths & nothing works, but everything works in the local development build.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the log files weren't showing all the errors for some reason -- there was a typo in one of my imports. :)